# PasteValues to next blank cell adjacent to the test column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to paste a range of cells in column "L" based on the position of the first blank cell in column "F."  This is what I have thus far"

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")

      .Range("H4:I" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy     'January
        Workbooks("2017 Plan.xlsx").Sheets("Consolidated").Range("L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues     'paste to 1+ rows paste last row used

End With
```

The first part works fine, but when I try to find where the first blank in column "F" the assignment value to start in column "L" throws an error. The range the data will be pasted to is in a table. Any insight will be much appreciated.

Comment: First version of following comment deleted because of error introduced while editing down to 500 characters.

Comment: It is NEVER a good idea to string commands together like this. It takes time to create the string and longer to debug it if it goes wrong. Is the last used row in column "A" 4 or more? Copying visible cells seems a strange way to get what you want. Break this up. Store the result of the first statement in a range variable. Check that range variable contains the range you expect. Store the result of the second statement in a range variable. Check that range variable contains the cell you expect. Debug.Print Rng.Address is helpful. Use `Rng1,Copy Destination:=Rng2` to copy the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always qualify which sheet is being referred to when using properties such as `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows`, etc:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
   'This line is missing a qualification of `Rows`
   '.Range("H4:I" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy     'January
    .Range("H4:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy     'January

   'This line is missing qualification of Cells and Rows
   'Workbooks("2017 Plan.xlsx").Sheets("Consolidated").Range("L" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues     'paste to 1+ rows paste last row used
    Workbooks("2017 Plan.xlsx").Sheets("Consolidated").Range("L" & Workbooks("2017 Plan.xlsx").Sheets("Consolidated").Cells(Workbooks("2017 Plan.xlsx").Sheets("Consolidated").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues     'paste to 1+ rows paste last row used

End With
```

Now that last statement is getting a bit unwieldy, so we can simplify the coding by using a `With` block:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("H4:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy     'January
End With

With Workbooks("2017 Plan.xlsx").Sheets("Consolidated")
    .Range("L" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues     'paste to 1+ rows paste last row used
End With
```

---

EDIT:  After chatting with XLMatters, we discovered that the normal approach of finding the last used cell in a column would not work, because the destination was within a table.  The code that ended up being used was:

```
With Workbooks("2017 Plan.xlsx").Sheets("Consolidated")
    .Range("L" & .Cells(2, "F").End(xlDown).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

---

A more robust method for finding the last cell and pasting the results would be:

```
dim lastRow As Long
With Workbooks("2017 Plan.xlsx").Sheets("Consolidated")
    lastRow = .Columns("F").Find(What:="*", _
                                 After:=.Cells(1, "F"), _
                                 Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                 MatchCase:=False).Row
    .Range("L" & lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

Comment: I tried the above, it appears to run.  Although, nothing gets pasted to "Consolidated" sheet.  Could it be my `.end(xlUp).Row).Offset(1,0)` statement.  I feel as though it is in the wrong position ??

Comment: `.Range("L" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)` is finding the cell in column L which has the same row number as the last non-empty cell in column F, and then `.Offset(1, 0)` is finding the cell one row below it.  You could also have done `.Range("L" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row+1)` and thus avoided the `Offset`, but there should be nothing wrong with what you have.

Comment: Your block solution works to a point, however I could not locate where the data was going to.  Finally, I found out where the data was pasting to.  It is pasting one row past my table range.  The trick I need is to get it to past in column "L" one row paste the used cells in column "E" within

Comment: @XLmatters If you need it to go in column L one row past the used cells in column E, rather than one row past the used cells in column F (as per your question), change `"F"` to `"E"`.

Comment: Sorry, typo.   One row past "F".  As in the code above

Comment: One row past last data in "F", to start the paste in column "L" but within the table.

Comment: @xlmatters - what is the row number of the last row which contains a value in column F?

Comment: The table name is "Table1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132031/discussion-between-yowe3k-and-xlmatters).

Comment: @XLmatters - I have updated the answer to use `Find` to get the last used cell - that will work irrespective of whether the last cell is inside a table or not.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for your help YowE3K.

Comment: Yes, agreed.  The `Find` method is more robust and seems to run faster.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to define a `Worksheet` object and `Set` it to `Workbooks("2017 Plan.xlsx").Sheets("Consolidated")`, than to remember to re-type the whole thing correctly the throughout your code.

Second, since you are using `PasteSpecial` to only copy the values, you don't need the brackets, you can put the `xlPasteValues` with a space.

**Comment**: You are searching for last row looking at Column A, while copying the data from Columns H:I, if the data in Column A not aligned, the result might not be what you are looking for.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteSpecialValues()

Dim ConsolSht   As Worksheet

Set ConsolSht = Workbooks("2017 Plan.xlsx").Sheets("Consolidated")

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("H4:I" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy  ' January
    ConsolSht.Range("L" & ConsolSht.Cells(ConsolSht.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Compile Error: Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property" when using the above code.

Comment: @XLmatters - You might be getting that error if you have other code in your module, and you placed **all** of Shai's code (including the `Option Explicit` line) below your existing code.  The `Option Explicit` command needs to be the first line within the code module.  (It **can** come after things like `Option Base 0`, but **normally** it will be the first line in the code module.)